# VBA Autofilter using logical AND across Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where I have a list of dates and I want to exclude some of those dates. The problem is that some of those dates have more than one value, and there is a specific value that I want to exclude for each date. The problem is that the value I wish to exclude is not exclusive to those dates so I need the logical equivalent of AND where I exclude those rows with those dates and value.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("table")
.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>17/08/2016", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>18/11/2016"
.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>-350"   
.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

The code above removes all rows with date 18/11/2016 before I have the chance to condition on the value. Conversely if I condition on the <>-350 first it removes that values that value from all dates including the ones I want to keep. So I want to be able to filter such that the date AND the value match is this possible in VBA?

Comment: You need an advanced filter, not an autofilter.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use an advanced filter in VBA?

Comment: So, do you want the code to hide the row **only if in the table first column there is NOT `17/08/2016` date and also NOT -350  in its fourth column**? So, if it is `19/08/2016` in first column but -350 in the fourth one, **that row should be visible**. Is this understanding a correct one?

Comment: Yes your reasoning is correct. I only want to exclude values where the date matches, 17/08/2016 only has one value so there is no issue. However 18/11/2016 has two values but I only want to exclude the one that is not -350. I do however want to keep the -350 values for all other dates such as 19/08/2016  as per your example.

Comment: The VBA is not the important part (you can record that) - you need to set up ranges on the sheet for the criteria. Have a look at Debra's advanced filter tutorials here: https://www.contextures.com/excelfiltertopics.html